# C Segmentation Fault on simple encryption code

Tags: c, encryption, segmentation-fault

I'm working on making an encryption code for class which continually splits a string down in half until there are only 1 or 2 chars left, in which you swap with the split chars to its right. However when i run the code I continually get this error:

```
INPUT A PHRASE: 1234
LENGTH: 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Below is my source code, if anyone could help me resolve this issue it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encrypt(char *str, int size);

int main(){
    char input[8192];
    int length;

    printf("INPUT A PHRASE: ");
    fgets(input, 8192, stdin);
    length = strlen(input) -1;
    printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);

    encrypt(input, length);
    printf("ENCRYPTION: %s\n", input);  
    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char str[], int size){

    char *final;

    int i;
    int k = size / 2;

    char *left = strncpy(left, str, k);
    encrypt(left, k);

    char *right = strncpy(right, str + k, size - k);
    encrypt(right, size - k);

    if(size <= 2 && size > 0){
        final = strcat(final, right);
        final = strcat(final, left);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing uninitialized vvariable to `strncpy()` and `strcat()` is a bad idea. It seems you also have other problems.

Comment: The problem is inifinite recursion because you always call `encrypt(left, k);` in function `encrypt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strncpy` takes a buffer as the first parameter, where to copy the data to. In your case you pass to it an uninitialized pointer instead:

```
char *left = strncpy(left, str, k);
```

The correct would be something like:

```
char left[SOME_SIZE];
strncpy(left, str, size); //size should not be greater than SOME_SIZE
```

And the same with `right` variable. Reference: [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)